# Python-Using character exclusion and quantifiers in a lookbehind to ignore characters if they exist

Tags: python, regex

Want to be able to grab a string with regex that is able to grab values regardless of whether or not something exists in a lookbehind.
E.g. the two strings below

```
    string_1 = "this('isastring', 'secondstring')"
    string_2 = "this(\\'issomeotherstring\\', \\'ADiffSecondString\\')
```

What I want to be able to do is to grab what is inside the quotes on the second string regardless of whether or not they have the double backslashes. I tried using a lookbehind with a character exclusion and quantifier but got an error where a lookbehind must be zero-width. Sorry very new to regex.

Comment: Write a parser that will yield you the tokens you need. A regex won't help unless you can use PyPi regex module.

Comment: @Jan, using lazy dot matching to parse a string literal with escape sequence is a way to nowhere. I already got too many downvotes for choosing that route. Good luck. Unless you match the whole string with \G and anchor at both sides, and access captures, this is out of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "grab", you mean find all strings, you can do as follow:

```
string_1 = "this('isastring', 'secondstring')"
string_2 = "this(\\'issomeotherstring\\', \\'ADiffSecondString\\')"

import re

findall_str = re.compile(r"\\?'(.*?)\\?'").findall

print(findall_str(string_1))
print(findall_str(string_2))
```

You'll get:

```
['isastring', 'secondstring']
['issomeotherstring', 'ADiffSecondString']
```

Comment: In regards to the subject, is there actually a way to do a variable length lookbehind so that quantifiers can exist? You have an elegant solution to this specific problem, but I guess for future use cases?

Comment: Lookbehind only accept fixed length pattern. Instead, you can used groups to store what's before / what's after and do a substitution (with a function) which preserve the before/after matches.